# How to bind json datasource to kendoScheduler

Tags: kendo-ui

How do I bind Json data to kendoscheduler. Javascript. I am new to kendo products. I am able to get Json data to show in Fullcalendar

```
  {
    "title":"Graduation Ceremony Group H",
    "start":"4/23/2015",
    "end":"4/23/2015",
    "description":"901 Boulevard Street"
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to build its datasource and then put the datasource to the scheduler..

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date("2013/6/6")
});

var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
var dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Interview"
    }
  ]
});

scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Read following documentation to help you build your own scheduler with proper datasource so its fit what you need..

[DataSource Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource)

[Scheduler DataSource Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/schedulerdatasource)

[Scheduler Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler)